# Whole word entity search on Wikidata

Tags: wikidata, wikibase

Wikidata [`wbsearchentities`](https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=wbsearchentities) service seems perform prefix-based matching, e.g. [searching for *novel*](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Special:ApiSandbox#action=wbsearchentities&format=json&search=novel&language=en&limit=max) matches as expected:

- *novel* : narrative text, normally of a substantial length and in the form of prose describing a fictional and sequential story

but for instance also:

- *novelist* : writer of novels
- *Novellara* : Italian comune

The documentation doesn't specify any special syntax for the `search` parameter: do we have a simple way of forcing whole-word matching?